# xmltask remove doesn't work

Tags: ant, xmltask

I have this application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application id="Application_1326308152661" version="1.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/application_1_4.xsd">
   <description>MIC Server Application.</description>
   <module>
      <web> ...         
      </web>
   </module>
   <module>
      <ejb>mic-sqlbridge.jar</ejb>
   </module>
   <security-role> ...
   </security-role>
</application>
```

In this xml the part 'module' tag containing the tag ejb must be removed. To do this I tried

```
<xmltask source="application.xml" dest="application_X.xml"> 
   <remove path="/application/module[ejb/text() = 'mic-sqlbridge.jar']"/> 
</xmltask>
```

Unfortunately this didn't remove anything - here's the log part:

```
[xmltask] Reading application.xml
[xmltask] Executing xmltask 1.16
[xmltask] Processing application.xml into application_X.xml
[xmltask] Using predefined xml catalog
[xmltask] Applying RemovalAction() to /application/module[ejb/text() = 'mic-sqlbridge.jar']
[xmltask] Applied RemovalAction() - 0 match(es)
[xmltask] RemovalAction() (/application/module[ejb/text() = 'mic-sqlbridge.jar']) failed to match
[xmltask] Normalizing resultant document
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Frank

Comment: Your path expression does not select the module element that you want. You should try making sure that you have the right expression first.

Comment: The propblem is the namespace... Using /*[local-name()='application'] instead of /application allowed me to delete the node /application/module/ejb - but it seems to be more difficult to delete the full tag 'module' that contains this ejb tag.

Answer (score 5):

Reading [this](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/11/01/xml-manipulation-using-xmltask.html#paths-and-namespaces) brought me the solution: "Scoping each XML element name with a preceding ':' is sufficient to tell the XPath mechanism that you're interested in the local name of the element."

So the path statement

```
path="/application/module[ejb/text() = 'mic-sqlbridge.jar']"
```

becomes

```
path="/:application/:module[:ejb/text() = 'mic-sqlbridge.jar']"
```

what worked perfectly.